# no line break between input text and <a>

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Within a form I have an text input and a `<a>` representing a button to add one more input element.

```
<div class="col-4">                          
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Menge" name="txt_menge[]" value="3">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add"><img src="../img/add-icon.png"/></a>
</div>
```

Currently each element has its own line, but they should be together in one line:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Bootstrap classes are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using `d-flex` instead of `col-4`

As in: `<div class="d-flex">`

Another approach would be using row and column of bootstrap, as in

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col">
Input here..
</div>
 <div class="col">
Button here..
</div>
</div>
```

refs: [Bootstrap Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/), [Bootstrap flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/),
[Bootstrap Forms](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/)

[image]

Comment: I could have thought of that myself... I´ve using the form grid and added one column per item

Answer (score 1):

add following code in **css**:

```css
.col-4{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-between;
  width:300px;
  height:auto;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-radius:5px;
}

.col-4 input{
  width:250px;
  height:100%;
  font-size:1rem;
  border:none;
  padding:1rem 0.4rem;
  outline:none;
}

.col-4 a{
  height:fit-content;
  }

.col-4 a img{
  width:40px;
  height:40px
}
```

```html
<div class="col-4">                          
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Menge" name="txt_menge[]" value="3">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add"><img src="../img/add-icon.png"/></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).